# How to reopen a pysimplegui window?

Tags: python, pygame, pysimplegui

I have some code that uses pygame to create a button. When this button is pressed, a pysimplegui window is opened. When this pysimplegui window is closed it cannot be reopened again. I was wondering if there was some way of reoping the window.

Code for pygame button:

```
def button(msg,x,y,w,h,ic,ac,action =None):
    if x + y > mouse[0] > x and y + h > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ac,(x,y,w,h))
        
        if click[0] == 1 and action!= None:
            
            if action == "play":
                asdc(window)
                
                
            if action == "quit":
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ic,(x,y,w,h))


    smallText = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms",20)
    textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg, smallText)
    textRect.center = ((round(x+(w/2))), (round(y + (h/2))))
    gameDisplay.blit(textSurf, textRect)
```

Code for pysimplegui button:

```
def asdc(window):
    while True:
        event, values = window.Read()
        if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED: 
            break
        
        if event == 'Enter':                            
            event, values = window.Read()    
            AllyBan1 = values["AllyBan1"]
            AllyBan2 = values["AllyBan2"]
            AllyBan3 = values["AllyBan3"]
            AllyBan4 = values["AllyBan4"]
            AllyBan5 = values["AllyBan5"] 
            
                break
                
    window.close()
```

How the code is run:

```
while True:
    gameDisplay.fill(white)

    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

    button("Enter",100,150,100,50,darkgreen,green,"play")
    button("Exit",450,150,100,50,darkred,red,"quit")

    for event in pygame.event.get() :
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT :
            pygame.quit()

            quit() 
    pygame.display.update()
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only use the layout and window objects once. After you close the window, you need to create a new one.

Try this code:

```
def createwindow():
    layout = [[sg.Text("Hello from PySimpleGUI")], [sg.Button("OK")]]
    return sg.Window("Demo", layout)

def button(msg,x,y,w,h,ic,ac,action =None):
    if x + y > mouse[0] > x and y + h > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ac,(x,y,w,h))
        
        if click[0] == 1 and action!= None:
            
            if action == "play":
                window = createwindow()  # must create each time
                asdc(window)
                
            if action == "quit":
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ic,(x,y,w,h))

    smallText = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms",20)
    textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg, smallText)
    textRect.center = ((round(x+(w/2))), (round(y + (h/2))))
    gameDisplay.blit(textSurf, textRect)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can minimize (hide) your window without closing and make it available to open again.

Example:

```
#Open window
old_windows()

# Hide old_windows()
window.hide()

#reopen old_windows()
window.unhide()

#open new window
window.hide()
new_window()
```